# Having error while letting users post comments and loading comments on a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

This is my Comments_controller file,

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.save

    redirect_to @posts

  end

  def destroy
  end

  end
end
```

This is the HTML for using it,

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>

<%= @post.text %>
<h2>Comments</h2>

<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <p><%= comment.text %></p>
    <p><%= time_ago_in_words comment.created_at %> ago </p>
<% end %>

<%= form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.text_area :text, :size => "40x10" %></p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Post Comment" %></p>
<% end %>

<p>
<%= link_to "Back", posts_path %>
|
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post) %> 
|
<%= link_to "Delete", @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

So when the user post's comments or when the user tries to load comments page this error occurs.

Comment: just remove one `end` from the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController 
 def create 
   @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = @post.comments.build(params[:comment])
   @comment.save
   redirect_to @posts
 end
 def destroy 

 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One end is extra in your controller code

Comment: I believe that is the answer. The error shown is syntax error. The syntax error is one extra end keyword.